# Which component designates the entry point of an activity?

Tags: java, android

[image]

The app I'm working on has several tabs on the bottom,and they're all part of the same Activity. Upon launching the app, the first tab to get the focus is always the same one.
I want to know which component of the app makes it behave that way.

Comment: I believe the first focusable control in xml gets the focus first. you can set "focusable" attribute for your control to avoid getting focus, or change control order in the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the `navigation` resource directory in `res` folder and find the navigation file which associated with this behavior. Open the navigation file and there you will see multiple `<fragments` listed.

At the top of this file you will find a `<navigation` block which will have something like `app:startDestination="@+id/"ID"`

In your file you will find something else at the place of `ID` and that is the id of the fragment which will come first when you open the activity.

So for you answer it is **`app:startDestination`** which is responsible for giving the focus to the first fragment when you launch the app.

Comment: I can't 'navigation' folder in the app. Is there a possibility that it wasn't in the apk? or did I miss something?

Comment: If your app is running perfectly in you Android Studio IDE after you compile it, then it must be there. Maybe if it is a multi-module app, you can look for it in other modules.